# SQL statement not correct

Tags: sql, security

If I want Account Albert to retrieve or modify any relation except DEPENDENT and 
can grant any of these privileges to other users, How will I do that?

I tried the GRANT function like so:

```
GRANT SELECT EMPLOYEE to Albert 
GRANT SELECT DEPARTMENT to Albert 
GRANT SELECT DEPT_LOCATIONS to Albert 
GRANT SELECT PROJECT to Albert 
GRANT SELECT WORKS_ON to Albert
```

But how do I let albert Modify?

Schema:

```
EMPLOYEE (Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, 
Super_ssn, Dno)
DEPARTMENT (Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date)
DEPT_LOCATIONS(Dnumber, Dlocation)
PROJECT(Pname, Pnumber, Plocation, Dnum)
WORKS_ON(Essn, Pno, Hours)
DEPENDENT(Essn, Dependent_name, Sex, Bdate, Relationship)
```

Comment: What database platform? Normale something like grant insert,update,delete ...

Answer (score 0):

So far you only grant SELECT rights. You want to grant UPDATE, too. And maybe INSERT and DELETE?

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE on EMPLOYEE to Albert ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it :

GRANT SELECT on EMPLOYEE to Albert 
GRANT SELECT on DEPARTMENT to Albert 
GRANT SELECT on DEPT_LOCATIONS to Albert 
GRANT SELECT on PROJECT to Albert 
GRANT SELECT on WORKS_ON to Albert
```